# What is the difference between the '[]' property and the '@each' property in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I've noticed that the enumerable mixin has computed properties that depends on the `'[]'` property, while ember arrays also have the `'@each'` property.

What is the difference between depending on `'[]'` and `'@each'`?

My vague understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) is that `'[]'` is triggered when the array content is replaced. But is this different than depending on the property itself?

Consider the the following class:

```
C = Ember.Object.extend({
  things: null,
  watcher1: (function() {
    console.log('watcher1')
  }).observes('things.[]'),
  watcher2: (function() {
    console.log('watcher2')
  }).observes('things.@each')
});
```

And I create an instance as follows:

```
c = C.create({things: Ember.A(['a', 'b'])});
```

The following:

```
c.get('things').replace(0, 1, ['z'])
```

triggers `watcher1` and `watcher2`

And the following:

```
c.get('things').setObjects(['1', '2'])
```

also triggers `watcher1` and `watcher2`

As does:

```
c.get('things').addObject('v')
```

So is there any difference? When should we use one vs. the other?

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Use `@each` if you need to observe properties of array elements**

`@each` supports observing properties of the elements inside the array. For example, `people.@each.name`. The bracket notation does not support this. Here is a [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ikedam/1/edit).

`@each` is a [property of Array instances](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/array.js#L418) that returns an [`EachProxy` instance](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/each_proxy.js#L83) that handles the delegation. On the other hand, `[]` simply [returns `this`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/array.js#L120).

**Use `[]` if you need it to work on non-Array enumerables**

According to the ember changelog, the bracket notation was made defunct in favor of `@each` in ember [0.9.4](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/CHANGELOG#L833), but then re-enabled in [0.9.8](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/CHANGELOG#L687). [The commit that re-enables it](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/d5e659bc8a8abaa3524bf66b7eb9b8f1bcdd18a3) indicates that `[]` can be used for non-Array enumerables such as `Ember.Set` instances. [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ojodas/1/edit).

Comment: The current official documentation –  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__each makes it  quite clear when to use which.