# Computed property on an Ember object not working

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember object as follows:

```
App.Basket = Ember.Object.extend({

    items: [],

    numItems: function () {
        return this.items.length;
    }.property('items'),

    addItem: function (item) {
        this.items.push(item);
        window.console.log(this.items.length, this.get('items').length, this.numItems);
    }

});

App.userBasket = App.Basket.create({
    items: [{name: 'testing'}]
});
```

It's bound to in a template with:

```
{{App.userBasket.numItems}}
```

It shows the initial value correctly as set by populating the items array on create.

However, I have a button that calls `App.userBasket.addItem({name: 'testing2'});`.

In the console, the correct counts are returned. However, the view doesn't update. Why is this?

Comment: instead of this.items.push(item); use pushObject: this.items.pushObject(item); and change your property to observe items.@each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `items.[]` to your computed property dependencies. Otherwise it will just observe changes in the array assigment like `basket.set('items', someItems)`, and you also want to observe changes in the array itself:

```
numItems: function () {
    return this.items.length;
}.property('items', 'items.[]'),
```

`items.push` is the native method from `Array`, ember add one called `pushObject` it behaves the same way like `push`, but notify the observes. And this is needed to `numItems` know about changes in the `items` property

```
addItem: function (item) {
    this.items.pushObject(item);
    window.console.log(this.items.length, this.get('items').length, this.numItems);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in some cases you might need to use `@each` instead of `[]` - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321885/what-is-the-difference-between-the-property-and-the-each-property-in-emb) is a good explanation as to the difference between the two.